# dbms_output.put_line prints nothing in SQL Developer version 18.1.0.095

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, dbms-output

My database is:

Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.1.0.5.0 - 64bit

The company just gave me a new desktop with Windows 10. I installed SQL Developer version 18.1.0.095 Build 095.1630. Everything works fine except that dbms_output.put_line no longer prints anything. For example this simple script:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('hola');  
END;
```

simply gives me this:

[image]

Whereas on a Windows 7 Professional box, with SQL Developer version 4.2.0.17.089 Build 17.089.1709 connected to the same oracle instance, the exact same script does print out hola nicely. Look:

[image]

Also, Toad version 12.12.0.39 executes this script and prints out hola without an issue.

I see that one guy has the same problem with the same version of SQL Developer at here: https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/03/dbms_output-in-sql-developer/ 
Check the comment section.

Could this be a bug with version 18.1.0.095?

Answer (score 5):

try the following

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
BEGIN...

Answer (score 3):

The answer is here:

[sqldeveloper - DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE() Doesn't Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49803808/sqldeveloper-dbms-output-put-line-doesnt-work?rq=1)

which says that SQL Developer 17 and above does not support Oracle 10g.

No wonder.

I've installed version 4.2, and now it's all good.

Comment: I totally missed the most important part of the question (10.1.0.5.0 - 64bit) - we haven't supported that version of Oracle in a LOOOONG time. I am guessing the 12cR2 jdbc driver update that came in at some point 'broke' this - but you really need to upgrade your database.

Comment: I would if I had the power of making such decisions. Suppose that I want to keep SQL developer version 18.1, is there any shim or hack that can make dbms_output.put_line work with Oracle 10g?

Comment: Not that I know of. Look at how old 10g is and then go and look at how new 18.1 is.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using sql developer 18.x and the answer from one of the comment threads helped me.
Answer:go to View -> DBMS Output window,
Run the script,
view output in DBMS output window.